# Сохранение истории поиска android

Tags: android, java

Сопсно вопрос вот такой, пишу программу которая ищет слова и мне нужно сохранить слово которое искали, и то что выдало по этому слово, то есть выдачу. Как мне сохранить всю историю поиска ? Куда сохранять?

Comment: В sqlite базу не подойдет?

Comment: та уже понял что по другому никак...

Comment: в книге pro android (от apress) вроде была глава про работу с поиском (сейчас на работе, книга не под рукой, так что может быть я ошибаюсь)

Comment: та тут не обычный поиск, в том то и дело)) придется свою базу делать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читайте в документации [Adding Recent Query Suggestions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html)